# Why can't we use conservation of mechanical energy here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, dissipation

> Consider a particle of mass $\text{m}$ fired from below into a bob of mass $\text{M}$ of a **long, simple pendulum**. The particle remains inside the bob and the bob rises through a height of $1.8\text{ m}$. What was the speed of the particle just before striking the bob?

I took the bob, the particle and the earth to be in a system and reasoned that their total mechanical energy must be conserved, since no external forces act on the system and all internal forces are (I think) conservative.

Then, I set my reference line for measuring potential energy to be at the level of the bob before the collision. The kinetic energy of the system just before the collision must be equal to the gravitational potential energy at the highest point of the bob's motion.

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}mv^2&=(M+m)gh \\
v &= \sqrt{\frac{2(M+m)gh}{m}} \end{align}$$

However, my textbook uses the principle of conservation of linear momentum and the laws of kinematics:

> If $\text{V}$ is the velocity of the combined mass after the collision, $(M+m)V=mv$. This gives:
> $$V=\frac{mv} {M+m}$$
> As the string becomes loose and the bob goes up with a deceleration of $\text{g}$, coming to rest at a height $\text{h}$, we can use the equation $v^2=u^2+2ax$.
> $$h=\frac{V^2}{2g}=\frac{m^2v^2}{2g(M+m)^2}$$
> $$v=\frac{M+m}{m}\sqrt{2gh}$$

Why did we get a larger answer this time? My intuition is that be conserving the mechanical energy of the system in the first method, I ignored possible energy losses in the deformation of the bob. Is my intuition correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $v$ you solved for is the velocity of the particle and bob together after they have collided. But the problem asks for the velocity of the particle before it has struck the bob. Your calculation wasn't wrong, you're just not finished with the problem yet.

To make it a little more clear the situation has three stages:

1. The particle has not yet collided with the bob. The bob has velocity 0 and the particle has velocity $v$.
2. The particle and the bob have collided but the pendulum has not risen. Both particle and bob have the same velocity $V$.
3. The pendulum has risen; the bob and particle both have velocity 0.

Energy is conserved between 2 and 3, but not between 1 and 2*. Momentum is conserved between 1 and 2. You need to use both conservation principles in the right place to get the correct final answer.

* Energy is lost as the bob and bullet deform. Collisions where the two objects stick together are called "perfectly inelastic" and have the minimum possible amount of energy conservation.